# Store the attribute's value of a WebElement in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, html-lists

Ive got a UL that is dynamically populated and the ID is also dynamically generated everytime you click on the "Action" button; is there a way to read the tag of the

```
<div class="class">
 <ul id="dynamically generated">
  <li class="li_class">
  <li class="li_class">
  <li class="li_class">
  <li class="li_class">
  <li class="li_class">
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention any language, I'll go with the [JAVA syntax](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)):

```
// String object 'field_value' is created
String fieldValue;  
// The field value is retrieved by the getAttribute("id") Selenium WebDriver predefined method and assigned to the String object.
fieldValue = _driver.findElement(By.ById("dynamically generated")).getAttribute("id")
```

It'll get the value of a the given attribute of the element. Will return the current value, even if this has been modified after the page has been loaded.

Comment: forgot about the ".getAttribute" function :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer but if some portion of the ID is stable, you can search for partial matches. For example, say you have an element

```
<span id="ctl00_SomeStableTextGoesHere_12345" ...>
```

where `12345` is dynamically generated. You could search for the start of the ID using CSS Selectors.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id^='ctl00_SomeStableTextGoesHere_']"));
```

There are other options:

- `^` begins with
- `$` ends with
- `*` contains